# unable to display minute through Timer

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to display time in a label.  My code is:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
        <div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="3000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
                    </asp:Timer>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Remaining Time:(Sec)"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="100"></asp:Label>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>

        </div>
```

and in `aspx` page

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label2.Text = Convert.ToString((Convert.ToInt32(Label2.Text) - 1));
        if (Convert.ToInt32(Label2.Text) == 0)
            Response.Redirect("~/Default2.aspx");
    }
```

It works fine, but i want to display the minute instead of the second.  Is there any method to do this?  Thanks.

Comment: @matthias Where this include in my code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your `Interval` to 60000 which should represent one minute.

Comment: Yap I unable to implement logic which is in your mind.Thanks a lot.I got what i want.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Label2.Text = Convert.ToString((Convert.ToInt32(Label2.Text) - 1)/60);
        if (Convert.ToInt32(Label2.Text) == 0)
            Response.Redirect("~/Default2.aspx");
    }
```